# related tables, how to find records if there are missing rows

Tags: sql

If two tables are releted and one table may have missing rows, how to find these records?

For example I have two tables: table1(with primary key "id", table2(with foreign key "id")
what I am trying to achieve is to get all records, where table1 record do not have counterpart in table2(missing row).

Comment: Make left join and check if corresponding part from table2 is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 AS t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXCEPT`/`EXCEPT ALL` can be used:

```
select id from table1
except all
select id from table2
```